# Dúvida chamada de função por laço

Tags: python

Bom tarde, sou iniciando em programação e estou com uma dúvida sobre chamado de função atraves de laço. Criei a função e estou tentando colocar para que ao final, pergunte se deseja continuar, caso aperto 0, o loop para contudo, apertando qlq outro numero, ele fica em loop sem dar resultado.

```
def somaimposto(taxaimposto, custo):
    return (1 + taxaimposto/100)*custo
    
taxaimposto = 10
custo = float(input('Qual o custo do produto: '))

print('O valor a ser vendido é de', somaimposto(taxaimposto, custo))

res = 1

while res:
    if(res):
        somaimposto(taxaimposto, custo)
    res = int(input("Digite 0 se desejar encerrar ou qualquer outro numero para continuar: "))
```

Comment: Dentro do seu `while` não tem `print` por isso não esta dando resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Vinicius, se eu entendi corretamente você quer calcular o valor a ser vendido baseado no custo do produto.

Seu código não funcionou pois não colocou as partes essenciais dentro do `while` loop. Seu programa funciona corretamente com a seguinte modificação:

```
def somaimposto(taxaimposto, custo):
    return (1 + taxaimposto/100)*custo
    

taxaimposto = 10
res = 1

while res:                # veja que movi esta parte que estava fora para dentro do loop
    if res:                                 
        custo = float(input('Qual o custo do produto: ')) 
        print('O valor a ser vendido é de', somaimposto(taxaimposto, custo))
        
    res = int(input("Digite 0 se desejar encerrar ou qualquer outro numero para continuar:"))
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudo demais!!

Answer (score 0):

Para você resolver esta questão você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def somaimpostos(taxa, cust):
    return (1 + taxa/100)*cust


while True:
    taxa_imposto = 10
    custo = float(input('Qual o custo do produto? '))

    print(f'R$ {somaimpostos(taxa_imposto, custo):.2f}')

    resp = input('Para encerrar digite "0" e qualquer outro valor para continuar! ')
    if resp == '0':
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos o código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Qual custo do produto?` . Neste momento devemos digitar o custo do produto e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida o código irá calcular e exibir o resultado. Depois recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Para encerrar digite "0" e qualquer outro valor para continuar!` . Neste momento se desejamos encerrar devemos pressionar "0" e pressionar `enter`. Caso queiramos continuar basta pressionarmos qualquer tecla e pressionar `enter`.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Agora entendi!

Comment: @Vinicius Araújo, Abraços.